# Use pages revox with angular 6

Tags: angular

Hi I have a templates provided by 
[Pages](http://pages.revox.io/dashboard/latest/doc/)

However I have no idea how to integrate them with my **Angular** project.
In the zipped file there is a demo app and get started app, but they don't launch and have no `angular.json` file. The structure is quite strange too,  except the apps there are a lot of html files and `css`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution I have found(still not sure about it)

There are two main folders in zip revox. One is called demo as they wrote - kind of ready app with different possibilities. Another one is called getting started. I'd recommend to start from this.
The main problem for me was setting up angular.
I am still not sure but as far as I understood

> There are many syntax and modules from angular 5, so make it work on angular 6 for me was impossible.
>   In order to make it work at all, I installed cli 6.0, then used ng cli update in order to change angular cli.json to angular.json (which is used in latest versions)

With this ready, I had cli 6.0, angular 5.2. So, how does this actually work? (I mean app) I want to tell again, that I am not sure completely, but here is my solution (the easiest one, probably) 
Open **getting started** folder, it wil be the project folder. 
Open **demo folder** - it will be used for modules and components(not all of them are present in getting started folder) 
Although in documentation, they say that you can just copy component and import it  into app.module.ts, I would suggest just using getting started app.mmodule.ts, with all that stuff already imported. If you created angular 6 project, and try to use components from zip archive. you will probably get errors (because of different versions of angular and some packages). So in general, you can just copy definite packages from demo, then in demo, watch where and how these components or modules are imported and where. That is how I understood that. If anybody needs further investigation, feel free to write below. Please note - that's just my suggestion which was found by practrical approach and way through mistakes and docs.
P.S. in demo they use different layouts like condensed and other ones, so routes are made in different way. You can choose one theme to use, and change routes just as you want them to be. Note that some routes (like in extra link) have subroutes (extra routes).